# Python aes ctr (cryptography.hazmat aes) similar inputs gives similar outputs

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes

This is my implementation of `AES-256-CTR` in `Python`, using the `cryptography.hazmat` module:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.algorithms import AES
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.modes import CTR
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend as backend
from base58 import b58encode,b58decode
import os

class AESCipher:
  def __init__(self,key):
    self.counter = 0
    self.key = key

    #AES 256 Requirement
    assert len(self.key) == 32

  def encrypt(self,plain_text):
    plain_text = plain_text.encode()
    self.counter += 1
    cipher = Cipher(AES(self.key),CTR(self.padCounter()),backend())
    encryption_engine = cipher.encryptor()
    cipher_text = self.padCounter() + encryption_engine.update(plain_text) + encryption_engine.finalize()
    return b58encode(cipher_text)

  def decrypt(self,cipher_text):
    cipher_text = b58decode(cipher_text)
    self.counter = cipher_text[:16]
    cipher = Cipher(AES(self.key),CTR(self.counter),backend())
    decryption_engine = cipher.decryptor()
    plain_text = decryption_engine.update(cipher_text[16:]) + decryption_engine.finalize()
    return plain_text.decode()

  def padCounter(self):
    return bytes(str(self.counter).zfill(16),"ascii")
```

When I encrypt similar messages, I get similar outputs:

```
>>> key = os.urandom(32)
>>> a = AESCipher(key)
>>> a.encrypt("message to encrypt one")
b'88SwQ7r6DKsuejgkEnxmGcQqjDdNAgd6vFZ7WLNB4oHBiqnxErpj'
>>> a.encrypt("message to encrypt two")
b'88SwQ7r6DKsuejgkEnxmGdKfTyyABe2JjpgbUK3poe2thiLGw5Et'
>>> a.encrypt("message to encrypt three")
b'3Psbq3enwAmwXGa2QejWFeyK8HS4DWCQrqSrWHxxbRzUsaYnYuKqEFZ'
>>> a.encrypt("message to encrypt four")
b'YTsV73Dg1QKhPZQRqss8QDKp7R2tgc3hShj5rdb911DeEqG1Jr4v9'
>>> a.encrypt("message to encrypt five")
b'YTsV73Dg1QKhPZQRqss8QJsVauew5vWjVEbEuvXufkmorxW46a44w'
>>> a.encrypt("message to encrypt six")
b'88SwQ7r6DKsuejgkEnxmGi4NDfNPe1wZ5KfFFLk93p7jBAA8nvqv'
>>>
```

There are lots of similarities in the outputs of the ciphertexts, is this expected behaviour ie the counter is from `0000000000000000` to `0000000000000001` and then in the XOR operations there's not a lot of difference, or have I messed up the implementation of AES?

Comment: Definitely not correct.  With AES-CTR, you do expect the property that related plaintexts produce related ciphertexts, and XORing plaintexts gives the same result as XORing the ciphertexts, but that's only if they use the same key and counter.  You're not resetting the counter between messages, so they should be absolutely unrelated.

Comment: A comparison is easier if the hex- instead of the Base58-encoded values are compared, e.g. the first and second value: `3030303030303030303030303030303154ed3a2b7d586076feb31e014a673c900a9dbc5e32cc` and `30303030303030303030303030303032178cef423dce5c5900a047bf3761724894baa21c8035`. The first 16 bytes are similar because this is implemented in the code _this way_: The nonce is placed before the ciphertext, starts with `30303030303030303030303030303031` and is incremented by `1` for each encryption. In the following data, which are the actual ciphertext, I can't see any correlations.

Comment: Apart from that your implementation is not harmless. For security reasons, CTR must not repeat a key/IV pair, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62030). 
In your code, the nonce starts with `30303030303030303030303030303031` each time an `AESCipher` object is instantiated, and is incremented by `1` for each encryption. This means that different keys must be used each time an `AESCipher` object is instantiated, otherwise key/IV pairs are repeated and you've a security issue.